# How to use twig object variable with at-sign @ inside

Tags: symfony, object, twig, special-characters, at-sign

I send from Symfony object which contains at-sign `@` in variable.
Object name is invoice and with `{{ dump(invoice) }}` in twig template I see object and parameter with path:

```
invoice[0].banSpojDod@showAs
```

But I dont know how to get value of this `banSpojDod@showAs` because there is at-sign `@`.

Could you help me someone please?

Comment: the `@` symbol is in the variable name? or value?

Comment: invoice[0]['banSpojDod@showAs']

Comment: I must ask... Why an @ in a variable name? Oo

Comment: Could try `invoice[0]['banSpojDod@showAs']`

Comment: @Matteo @ is in th variable name

Comment: Nothing works... I tried also `{{attribute(f.banSpojDod,'@showAs')}}` - `f` is one item in invoice array.

Comment: `{{ f.banSpojDod }}` works well but with parameter not

Comment: @Veve becouse I get json data to Symfony and then use json_decode to object. The  `@` symbol is inside json file.

Answer (score 2):

You could try with The [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function can be used to access a "dynamic" attribute of a variable:

```
{{ attribute(invoice[0], 'banSpojDod@showAs') }}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks. Problem was that I used it in loop, and some parameters not exists. I needed to add exist conditions. So my final code works:

`{% for f in invoice %}
    {% if attribute(f,'banSpojDod@showAs') is defined %}
       {{ attribute(f,'banSpojDod@showAs')  }}
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}`